# How do I write a csv from R without quoted values?

Tags: r, csv

I'm looking to create a csv from R where none of the values have quotes around them. This seems to be the norm when you create a CSV in excel but not in R.

Take the following example:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(Apples=sample(1:10, 5), Oranges=sample(1:10, 5), Bananas=sample(1:10, 5), Dates=sample(1:10, 5))
write.table(df, sep=",", row.names = FALSE)
```

If you open it in notepad you see the column headers have quotes around them. I need it to be without quotes if the csv is to be successfully imported into another program.

I noticed that re-saving the csv in Excel causes the quotes to disappear but I need to avoid having to make this step.

I tried things like `col.names = noquote(colnames(LineupCSV))` as an argument in `write.table` but without success.

How can I remove the quotes around values when I write a csv in R?

Comment: Use the `quote=FALSE` argument?

Comment: `write.csv(df,"df.csv", quote=F)`

Comment: We need to add an answer to have as a dupe target for this and possibly faq. Please add one @ekstroem

Comment: how did I not see that 4 hours of my life ago. thanks @ekstroem

Comment: @PierreLafortune Done

Comment: @WillT-E Well we've all been staring at the forest looking for the trees at some point

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to write a data frame as a csv file without quoting values and strings then you can set the `quote=FALSE` argument when calling `write.table` or one if its wrappers such as `write.csv` and `write.csv2`.

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(Apples=sample(1:10, 5), 
                 Oranges=sample(1:10, 5), 
                 Bananas=sample(1:10, 5), 
                 Dates=sample(1:10, 5))
write.table(df, file="~/test.csv", sep=",", row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Alternatively, you can use `fwrite` from the `data.table` package (at least from 1.97 onwards)

```
fwrite(df, file="~/test2.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `quote` argument inside `write.table()` function. Set it to **FALSE**

```
formalArgs(write.table)
# [1] "x"            "file"         "append"       "quote"        "sep"          "eol"          "na"           "dec"          "row.names"    "col.names"    "qmethod"     
# [12] "fileEncoding"

set.seed(100)

df <- data.frame(Apples=sample(1:10, 5), Oranges=sample(1:10, 5), Bananas=sample(1:10, 5), Dates=sample(1:10, 5))

write.table(df, file="MyFile.csv", sep=",", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```